# How could I clarify my question?

Tags: discussion, close-reasons, vote-to-close

I've met a quite [interesting problem](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/143016/14149) and I thought it would be a nice task also on the code golf.

Unfortunately, it is currently being held as *unclear*.

However, the problem is for me very simple and clear. To my best knowledge, I reacted and made clear all reactions in comments, and by improving the post. The question didn't get up, neither down votes.

Considering

- the numerous reactions about the details,
- the lack of up and also down votes,
- while the problem is quite simple and clear in my mind,

I think some major problem still could exist, which could make the post still unclear. But, by answering all comments and improving the post according them, I don't have more idea.

I think maybe the math-focused part makes the post partially offtopic. On this reason, I've made a [MathSE question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2432123/111704) and as it is visible in the answer, it has a very quick, simple and nice algorithm. This post is linked into the question.

@hvd pointed to a [problem](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/143016/approximate-real-number-with-n-digit-precision#comment350420_143016) about the exact formulation of the required algorithmic complexity. I think it was fixed in the post.

Comparing the current version of the post to its first, I see major differences. Any idea, what else to do?

Comment: It seems clear to me.

Comment: I voted to reopen the question about 10 minutes after you made the last clarifications concerning the complexity. So I think the question is clear now und you just need to wait until it's reopened.

Comment: Thank everybody the help!